# setting the size of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to be able to resize the JFrame when I click a button, so here's the code:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        try {

            JPanel source = (JPanel)arg0.getSource();
            JPanel parent = (JPanel)source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
            parent.getParent().setSize(new Dimension(1400,800));
                        ((JLayeredPane) parent.getParent()).revalidate();
}
```

but the code above is not resizing my JFrame, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(source); // where source is your button
window.setSize(new Dimension(1400,800));
```

Comment: Window is the parent class of Frame and Dialog (and grandparent of JFrame / JDialog...)